# getting error in the javascript ,when authenticate the username and password using digest authentication

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

here i want to authenticate the username and password .here im getting the username ,password vlues succesfully in console(valuesUser).
I tried the following code,

```
Ext.define('Form.controller.Digestauth', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires:['RegisterForm.view.Login','RegisterForm.view.Main'],
    config:{
        refs:{
            loginform: '#loginform'
        },
        control: {
            '#loginButton': {
                tap: function(){
                    var valuesUser = this.getLoginform().getValues();
                    console.log(valuesUser);
                    console.log(valuesUser.userName);
                    $.Class("pl.arrowgroup.DigestAuthentication",{
                        MAX_ATTEMPTS : 1,
                        AUTHORIZATION_HEADER : "Authorization",
                        WWW_AUTHENTICATE_HEADER : 'WWW-Authenticate',
                        NC : "00000001", //currently nc value is fixed it is not incremented
                        HTTP_METHOD : "GET",
                        /**
                           * settings json:
                           *  - onSuccess - on success callback
                           *  - onFailure - on failure callback
                           *  - username - user name
                           *  - password - user password
                           *  - cnonce - client nonce
                           */
                        init : function(settings) {
                            this.settings = settings;
                        },
                        setCredentials: function(username, password){
                            this.settings.username = valuesUser.username;
                            this.settings.password = valuesUser.userPassword;
                        },
                        call : function(uri){
                            this.attempts = 0;
                            this.invokeCall(uri);
                        },
                        invokeCall: function(uri,authorizationHeader){
                            var digestAuth = this;
                            $.ajax({
                                url: uri,
                                uri:'http://localhost/sencha2011/RegisterForm/newuser.php?action=check',
                                type: this.HTTP_METHOD,
                                beforeSend: function(request){
                                    if(typeof authorizationHeader != 'undefined'){
                                        request.setRequestHeader(digestAuth.AUTHORIZATION_HEADER, authorizationHeader);
                                    }
                                },
                                success: function(response) {
                                    digestAuth.settings.onSuccess(response);
                                },
                                error: function(response) {
                                    if(digestAuth.attempts == digestAuth.MAX_ATTEMPTS){
                                        digestAuth.settings.onFailure(response);
                                        return;
                                    }
                                    var paramParser = new pl.arrowgroup.HeaderParamsParser(response.getResponseHeader(digestAuth.WWW_AUTHENTICATE_HEADER));
                                    var nonce = paramParser.getParam("nonce");
                                    var realm = paramParser.getParam("realm");
                                    var qop = paramParser.getParam("qop");
                                    var response = digestAuth.calculateResponse(uri, nonce, realm, qop);
                                    var authorizationHeaderValue = digestAuth.generateAuthorizationHeader(paramParser.headerValue, response, uri);
                                    digestAuth.attempts++;
                                    digestAuth.invokeCall(uri, authorizationHeaderValue);
                                }
                            });
                    },
                            calculateResponse : function(uri, nonce, realm, qop){
                                var a2 = this.HTTP_METHOD + ":" + uri;
                                var a2Md5 = hex_md5(a2);
                                var a1Md5 = hex_md5(this.settings.username + ":" + realm + ":" + this.settings.password);
                                var digest = a1Md5 + ":" + nonce + ":" + this.NC + ":" + this.settings.cnonce + ":" + qop + ":" +a2Md5;
                                return hex_md5(digest);
                            },
                            generateAuthorizationHeader : function(wwwAuthenticationHeader, response, uri){
                                return wwwAuthenticationHeader+', username="'+this.settings.username+'", uri="'+
                                    uri+'", response="'+response+'", nc='+
                                    this.NC+', cnonce="'+this.settings.cnonce+'"';
                            }
                    });
                    $.Class("pl.arrowgroup.HeaderParamsParser",{
                        init : function(headerValue) {
                            this.headerValue = headerValue;
                            this.headerParams = this.headerValue.split(",");
                        },
                        getParam: function(paramName){
                            var paramVal = null;
                            $.each(this.headerParams, function(index, value){
                                if(value.indexOf(paramName)>0){
                                    paramVal = value.split(paramName+"=")[1];
                                    paramVal = paramVal.substring(1, paramVal.length-1);
                                }
                            });
                            return paramVal;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

to write the above code ,i take the help of "http://marcin-michalski.pl/2012/11/01/javascript-digest-authentication-restful-webservice-spring-security-javascript-ajax/" link  digest-auth.js file

im getting the error as :Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined.can anyone help me to do this .thanks in advance

Comment: You need to include the jQuery library.

Comment: That's too bad, because the code you have requires jQuery. From the link you gave: *"Below I’m presenting step by step what needs to be done in order to configure Spring Security and **jQuery** /Ajax client that calls secured resource."*

Comment: Hi Lucky, Is this working for you. If so can you please post the complete code? I am new to Sencha and I am struggling to use digest authentication for many days.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include jQuery. It defines a global `$` variable, which is what your error is complaining about. Probably from the call to [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Check out the Getting Started section here: http://docs.jquery.com/

Comment: can u tell me ,in my code ,where should i have to include jQuery library

Comment: It needs to be in the head section of your html. http://learn.jquery.com/about-jquery/how-jquery-works/

Comment: Not sure what's that about. You might ask another question with more details and someone might help you out.