# Getting an uncaught error when i included the jquery.js file

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following link contains my original question: "[getting error in the javascript ,when authenticate the username and password using digest authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14795352/getting-error-in-the-javascipt-when-authenticate-the-username-and-password-usin)"

By following the suggestions `I included the jquery.js file` and `jquery-1.4.2.min.js` files.  After that im getting the error as `"Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} has no method 'Class' ".`  Can anyone help me to solve this. Thanks in advance...

Comment: When are you calling `$.Class`?

Comment: in tap function,i called  $.Class.by using this http://marcin-michalski.pl/2012/11/01/javascript-digest-authentication-restful-webservice-spring-security-javascript-ajax/  link (digestauth.js),i wrote my code.

Comment: Why?  What are you trying to do with `$.Class`?

Comment: i want to authenticate  username and password ,using digest authentication

Comment: @lucky what is `jquery.js` file? Is it another jquery plugin?

Comment: no,it's a jquery library,someone gave the suggestion,to include the jquery library in my index file.that's why i included it.then im getting the above uncought typeerror

Answer (score 1):

You need to include the file located in this github repository to define the `Class` function.

```
https://github.com/Arrowgroup/JSDigestAuth/blob/master/src/main/webapp/resources/js/jquery.class.min.js
```

In fact looking at the example there, you will need all this in your header, if you don't have these script files in this order then you will get undeclared errors as you have seen in BOTH your questions.

> As an aside, a quick glance at this code shown it to be... well... let's just say "not so good."   As an example maybe it can be helpful but I saw many things which were not leading practices.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.class.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="md5-min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="digest-auth.js" ></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var digestAuth = new pl.arrowgroup.DigestAuthentication(
            {
                onSuccess : function(response){
                    $("#response").html(response);
                },
                onFailure : function(response){
                    $("#response").html('Invalid credentials !!!');
                },
                cnonce : 'testCnonce'
            }
        );
        function callREST(){
            digestAuth.setCredentials($('#user').val(),$('#password').val());
            digestAuth.call('/restauth/user/echo');
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: okay,thanks for your answer ,i will try this one.i have a doubt,can i include jquery.js library file ?

Comment: @lucky - you are special.  Over 80% of all websites on the internet include that file without problem, including this one.  please don't include it twice, `jquery.js` and `jquery.min.js` and `jquery-1.4.2.min.js` are all the same thing.  The file you are missing in this question is `jquery.class.min.js`

Comment: Hogan,i have a doubt,can u clarify? here im getting the form values in var valuesUser = this.getLoginform().getValues(); in the variable ,in the success function .but in github link they are using a button

Comment: @lucky - this is really a different question and reveals a fundamental  lack of understanding the functional requirements.  What exactly are you trying to do?  If you are trying to authenticate via a form then I would expect the submit would cause authentication on the server side.  If you are authenticating on the client then you **don't** want to submit the form but handle it in javascript.  In this case you would use a button and not an `<input>` of type submit.